# Parsing JSON Object in android, giving me blank page

Tags: java, android, json

I need to parse JSONObject. Whenever it runs the application, it gave me a blank page. Why is that so?  Did i code it wrongly?

This is my JSON Object structure:

```
  {
    "UserID": "",
    "Gender": "",
    "Password": "",
    "Name": "",
    "AddressLineOne": "",
    "AddressLineTwo": "",
    "AddressLineThree": "",
    "PostalCode": "",
    "HomeTel": "",
    "Email": ""
}
```

And this is my code to parse the JSONObject

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                 JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++) {

                    Profile profile = new Profile();

                    profile.setName(jsono.getString("Name"));
                    profile.setAddressLineOne(jsono.getString("AddressLineOne"));
                    profile.setAddressLineTwo(jsono.getString("AddressLineTwo"));
                    profile.setAddressLineThree(jsono.getString("AddressLineThree"));
                    profile.setPostalCode(jsono.getString("PostalCode"));

                    profileList.add(profile);


                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

Comment: No need of for loop to parse your `JSONObject`, for loop requires only for 'JSONArray'

Comment: Thank you for telling me this :) I removed the loop, it still give me a blank response.

Comment: Check if `data` string is not empty.

Comment: What do you mean? @user3819356

Comment: `String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` can return empty string because of empty `entity`, am I right?

Comment: Oh. then how am i supposed to check? @user3819356

Answer (score 0):

you did not add permission in your manifest file then add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use for loop if you do not have JSONArray. If you can provide how response look like, it would be much easier to answer.

Comment: I removed the loop. It still give me a blank response. I'm unable to upload a picture for you to see as i have insufficient reputation points

Answer (score 0):

**NO need of for loop if you not getting  array if you are getting jsonarray fist take out object of json form jsonarray and thane parse it you can also use gson for that 
using gson create pojo of your object and then  Gson gson = new Gson();
use method fromJson**

Answer (score 0):

Check your Json Object which you are getting as response. It may be they are sending you the object having blank string as you have posted in question. In this case it will show you blank page. Your code is right , just you have to remove the loop and check your Json object again.

Comment: It isnt a blank string. i just removed the data as it is confidential. sorry for misunderstood you >.<

Comment: There is no error in your parsing except the loop, it may happen you are calling this webservice on main thread. Are you using AsynchTask or calling it on main Thread.

Comment: Im using AsyncTask :) this isn't webservice.

Comment: can you print the object and show it in logcat that you are getting the object with all values filled.

Comment: Yes i can. I used " System.out.println(profile.getName()); " and it retrieved the correct name.

Comment: Ok, can you clearify one thing where are you showing this data and getting a blank page. Can you paste here the code to show the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
if (status == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Server response data is empty!");
    } else {

        // JSON parsing routine

    }

}
```

Comment: I followed your code and also declared LOG_TAG as " private static final String LOG_TAG = null; " 
When i run it, the emulator still shows me a blank page. The logcat has show several errors :
1. Couldn't load memtrack module(no file or directory) 
2. Failed to load memtrack: -2 
3. Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API 
4. glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 886277936 
5. got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot

Comment: Print your `data` to the logcat via `Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Data: " + data);` in the `else` clause and check if it is the same as expected (valid JSON string).